# pyInstaller executable missing module "_struct" on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller

I would like to package my python project into a UNIX executable. For this I've tried py2exe, cxfreeze and pyInstaller, but nothing worked. Hopefully you can help me with pyinstaller. So here it goes:

I've downloaded the zipfile of pyinstaller-2.0 from http://www.pyinstaller.org/ and unzipped it.

In the folder, I run `python pyinstaller.py ../helloworld.py` (output listed at the end).

Then I try to execute the file: `./helloworld/dist/helloworld/helloworld`
which gives me the output:

```
mod is NULL - structTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
mod is NULL - archiveTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-1.5.1/archive.py", line 42, in <module>
    import struct
ImportError: No module named struct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
ImportError: No module named archive
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7.3. My PYTHONPATH include /usr/lib/python2.7. It looks as if the problem is a missing module _struct, but I have no idea where to find it. I've tried pyinstaller 1.5.1 and the development version, neither work here.

Please help!

The output of `python pyinstaller.py ../helloworld.py`:

```
 7 INFO: wrote /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/helloworld/helloworld.spec
    27 INFO: UPX is not available.
    583 INFO: checking Analysis
    583 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
    583 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
    702 INFO: Analyzing /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/support/_pyi_bootstrap.py
    1570 INFO: Analyzing /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/archive.py
    1637 INFO: Analyzing /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/carchive.py
    1701 INFO: Analyzing /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/iu.py
    1720 INFO: Analyzing ../helloworld.py
    1721 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
    1721 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
    1721 INFO: Analyzing rthook /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/support/rthooks/pyi_rth_encodings.py
    2197 INFO: Looking for Python library libpython2.7.so
    objdump: section '.dynamic' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
    2308 INFO: Warnings written to /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/helloworld/build/pyi.linux2/helloworld/warnhelloworld.txt
    2311 INFO: checking PYZ
    2311 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
    2312 INFO: building PYZ out00-PYZ.toc
    2706 INFO: checking PKG
    2706 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
    2706 INFO: building PKG out00-PKG.pkg
    2711 INFO: checking EXE
    2712 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because helloworld missing
    2712 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
    2772 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /home/jelle/Downloads/pyinstaller-2.0/helloworld/build/pyi.linux2/helloworld/helloworld
    2773 INFO: checking COLLECT
    2773 INFO: building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
```

BTW: my helloworld.py simply contains the statement print "hello world". I tried putting #!/usr/bin/python2.7 at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the system variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It might point to the wrong python library libpython2.7.so.

In my case, I could fix this by resetting it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
```